# AWS Chalice - split the app.py in several files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chalice

I'm using chalice for an application with a lot of endpoints. I don't want to separate it in several lambdas, because they share the same code (which is in chalicelib), but I want to  separate somehow my `app.py` (e.g. I want it to be like app_user.py, app_sessions.py etc.) I'm not very good about Python core, but I think it should be possible to do it somehow using `__init__.py` to say the Chalice to glue my files together on the deployment.

tl;dr Is it possible to have something like `#include` from C in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this in Chalice, but there is an issue [#21](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/21) in their GitHub repo that has requested this feature.

Comment: I think you must have all endpoints declared in your `app.py`, but you can have your logic separated and make each endpoint function call a different internal package to process the request and respond. From the standpoint of organizing your code, it's not that bad; you only have to edit your `app.py` when you need to add, change or remove an endpoint.

Comment: @RenatoByrro Ye, that's exactly what I do now. Code seems to be rather clean. Thanks.